# RSpec: application layout rendering blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines

I am working in a mountable engine, which might have something to do with this problem. I have a page on which I am trying to test for the presence of some content. Right now, I have hardcoded an inline template.

pagescontroller#show:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { 
      render inline: "<p>Dummy content</p>", layout: 'myengine/application'
    }
  end
end
```

relevant spec from pages_spec.rb:

```
it "should have the right content" do
  visit 'my_url'
  puts "page.body:", page.body

  # right now, pagescontroller renders any layout as blank. That's why page.body is always blank
  expect(page.body).to have_content 'Dummy content'
end
```

When I run the spec, I get this:

```
page.body:
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
F

Failures:

  1) MyEngine::PagesController the page should have the right content
     Failure/Error: expect(page.body).to have_content 'content'
       expected to find text "content" in ""
     # ./spec/controllers/myengine/pages_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have verified that rails is looking for the application layout in the right place and if I give it a layout that doesn't exist, it lets me know that it couldn't find it. So I know it's finding *something* called `/app/views/layouts/myengine/application.html.erb`. But it's not rendering anything that's in `/app/views/layouts/myengine/application.html.erb`.

If I comment out the layout from the render line in pagescontroller#show to be `render inline: "<p>Dummy content</p>"#, layout: 'myengine/application'`, it works fine. `page.body` has the `<p>Dummy content</p>`.

Another note: when I do this in the browser, it renders the application layout as expected, so I suspect it has something to do with RSpec.

Any ideas why this is happening? Why is it rendering any layout I give as blank? Do I need to do something else here since I'm testing the dummy application within a mountable engine?

**Edit:**
Here is my `layouts/myengine/application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyEngine</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "myengine/application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "myengine/application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <% if noindex? %><meta name="robots" value="noindex" /><% end %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

  <% if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <% end %>

  <div id="ruler"></div>

  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <script type="text/javascript">Materialize.toast('<span class="<%= key %>"><%= value %></span>', 8000);</script>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>

  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is in your `layouts/myengine/application.html.erb`?

Comment: Added the contents of the file to the question.

Comment: I don't believe you are supposed to specify the engine name when you specify the layout. I believe an engine is supposed to look just like an app. (Been a while last I worked with an engine.)

Comment: Try to visit the page in the browser and see if it gives you an error. Maybe there is a bug in the layout.

Comment: Try `layout: false` and see if your test passes. It should just spit out the `inline` option verbatim.